# Installer cannot see the windows drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, boot-partition

Similar problems have been reported in a couple of posts on the Net but the solutions suggested do not resolve my issue hence this post.

I have a HP Stream laptop running Windows 10 and sometime ago I managed to install Ubuntu on a SD card and dual boot with windows by creating Ubuntu /boot partition on the Windows drive. This works perfectly well (SD card is not a bootable device and hence the need for this tweak).

Yesterday, I thought of upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10. On liveCD I ran gparted and it correctly picks up both eMMC drive (with Win10 and Ubuntu /boot partition) and the SD card (with Ubuntu). I can manually mount Win10 partitions and the /boot partition without any issues.

However, when I run the installer, it only picks up the SD card. If I eject the SD card, the installer claims that there are drives to install the OS.

To eliminate any issues with the iso, I tried Lubuntu 20.04 ISO which I have used for installations and it gives me the same problem - ie the installer cannot see the eMMC drive.

I could not find any obvious settings on UEFI which may need to be tweaked.

Appreciate if anyone has comments/suggestions.

Many thanks.

Comment: A separated /boot partition shouldn't be needed even if the drive isn't bootable (it doesn't have to be unless it contain the EFI partition which it doesn't because it already exists in the same internal drive where Windows is preinstalled).

Comment: And, as always, disabling Fast Startup in Windows is a must when dual-booting.

Comment: Please try and be specific with details; you mention Lubuntu 21.10 which I know uses the `calamares` installer; but you didn't give specifics on Ubuntu (which is available using `ubiquity`, `subiquity` & even a *canary* build...)  You didn't mention if it's Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server etc.

Comment: Instead of reinstalling, could you upgrade in place? `do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I did disable hibernation completely and turned off all power saving settings to 'never' on the disk drives. When I check the power settings I do not get the fast startup option at all presumably because the hibernation was turned off using 'powercfg.ext /H off' earlier?

Comment: @guiverc, currently running Ubuntu Studio 20.04 and trying install Ubuntu Studio 21.10

Comment: @OrganicMarble, I specifically want to do a clean install rather than an distribution upgrade because of other issues. Of course, I could wipe out the current 20.04 installation on the SD card, install 21.10 on it and move the /boot directory to eMMC card but just curious why the installer cannot see the eMMC drive when I can mount partitions on it from the LiveUSB.

Comment: Ubuntu is available in desktop form (using `ubiquity` by default), server form (using `subiquity`) so please be specific. Ubuntu Studio 21.10 uses `calamares` just as Lubuntu does so doesn't use the same installer as Ubuntu (it did though for 20.04). The more specific you are with details (the ISO used to install dictates the installer used) the better we an help you with.